# Парсинг строки на C# (ключ = значение с пробелами)

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

есть строка типом

`"cat=1 cn1=27427 cn1Label=EventID cnt=1 cs1=bad-unknown cs1Label=IDSClass cs2=preprocessor cs2Label=IDSGroup cs3= cs3Label=CVEID cs4= cs4Label=ExternalRef cs5= cs5Label=IDSTags deviceExternalId=758071121 deviceFacility=**Traffic anomaly** dmac=e3:e3:e0:01:00:02 dpt=547 dst=255.255.255.255 proto=UDP rt=**Mar 09 2021 09:32:15.135 MSK** smac=2c:ed:e1:e9:e5:e4 spt=546 src=0.0.0.0"`

Мне нужно получить все значения, пробовал регулярку, не помогло, т.к. берет только до пробела слово.

Comment: Двойные звёздочки присутствовали в исходной строке или же были вставлены для привлечения внимания?

Comment: Это было отредактировано не мной.

Comment: там должен быть жирный шрифт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Регулярка, которая осилит значения с пробелами: `(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>.*?)(?=(\s\w+=|$))`
здесь используется просмотр вперед для поиска следующей группы или конца строки.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var input = @"cat=1 cn1=27427 cn1Label=EventID cnt=1 cs1=bad-unknown cs1Label=IDSClass cs2=preprocessor cs2Label=IDSGroup cs3= cs3Label=CVEID cs4= cs4Label=ExternalRef cs5= cs5Label=IDSTags deviceExternalId=758071121 deviceFacility=Traffic anomaly dmac=e3:e3:e0:01:00:02 dpt=547 dst=255.255.255.255 proto=UDP rt=Mar 09 2021 09:32:15.135 MSK smac=2c:ed:e1:e9:e5:e4 spt=546 src=0.0.0.0";
var pattern = @"(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>.*?)(?=(\s\w+=|$))";
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["key"] + " = " + match.Groups["value"]);
```

Вывод:

```
cat = 1 
cn1 = 27427 
cn1Label = EventID 
cnt = 1 
cs1 = bad-unknown 
cs1Label = IDSClass 
cs2 = preprocessor 
cs2Label = IDSGroup 
cs3 =  
cs3Label = CVEID 
cs4 =  
cs4Label = ExternalRef 
cs5 =  
cs5Label = IDSTags 
deviceExternalId = 758071121 
deviceFacility = Traffic anomaly 
dmac = e3:e3:e0:01:00:02 
dpt = 547 
dst = 255.255.255.255 
proto = UDP 
rt = Mar 09 2021 09:32:15.135 MSK 
smac = 2c:ed:e1:e9:e5:e4 
spt = 546 
src = 0.0.0.0
```

[Пример работы](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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)

Comment: Это регулярное выражение захватывает пробел в конце `value`. Можно улучшить: `var pattern = @"(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>.*?)(?=( \w+=|$))";`

Comment: @Antosha, согласен, поправил, можно даже не пробел последний не включать, а любой пробельный символ `\s`, вероятно лучше было бы даже `\s+` взять

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю такой вариант, надеюсь поможет

```cs
public static Dictionary<string, string> ToNormalizedDictionary(this string input)
{
//видно что строка разделена пробелом, если больше одного пробела мы удаляем лишние
   string[] keyValuePairs = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//получаем словарь пары
   Dictionary<string, string> result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

   foreach (string pair in keyValuePairs)
   {
     // и потом по знаку равно еще данные разбираем
       string[] keyValue = pair.Split('=', StringSplitOptions.None);

       if (keyValue.Length == 2)
          result.Add(ToNormalizedKey(keyValue[0]), keyValue[1].Trim());
    }

       return result;
}

public static string ToNormalizedKey(this string input)
{
    if (input is null)
      return string.Empty;

    return new string(input
      .Trim()
      .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
      .ToCharArray()
      .Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark)
      .ToArray())
      .ToUpperInvariant()
      .NormalizeStringWithRegexPattern();
}

private static string NormalizeStringWithRegexPattern(this string string)
{
    return Regex.Replace(string, Pattern, PatternNormalize);
}

private const string Pattern = @"([^0-9A-Z]|\s)+";
private const string PatternNormalize = "_";
```

```cs
// Вызов метода чтобы строку нормализировать
string stroka = "cat=1 cn1=27427 cn1Label=EventID cnt=1 cs1=bad-unknown cs1Label=IDSClass cs2=preprocessor cs2Label=IDSGroup cs3= cs3Label=CVEID cs4= cs4Label=ExternalRef cs5= cs5Label=IDSTags deviceExternalId=758071121 deviceFacility="Traffic anomaly" dmac=e3:e3:e0:01:00:02 dpt=547 dst=255.255.255.255 proto=UDP rt="Mar 09 2021 09:32:15.135 MSK" smac=2c:ed:e1:e9:e5:e4 spt=546 src=0.0.0.0"
ToNormalizedDictionary(stroka);
```

```cs
stroka.TryGetValue("CAT", out string cat); // а тут вы указываете ключ и на выходе значение
```

Comment: я по ошибке воткнул кавычки в вопрос, исправил

Comment: Простой сплит по пробелу не осилит `rt=Mar 09 2021 09:32:15.135 MSK`

Comment: вы бы проверили решение, кажется оно не работает

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй такую регулярку.

```
(?<==)[^\s]*
```

Comment: Не осилит `rt=Mar 09 2021 09:32:15.135 MSK`

Comment: Тогда так `(?<==)[^=]*`, должно получится, но это не точно.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Ответы типа такого (предположения) лучше писать не в ответ, а в комментарии под вопросом. Ваша регулярка не работает.